# How to calculate intersect of elements of a list in R

Tags: r, reduce, intersect

I have 10 lists named : `Thre1`, `Thre2`, `Thre3`, `...`, `Thre10`.

My output should also be a list in a way that ith element of the output should be intersect of `i`th elements of my input lists so for example:

```
output[[1]] = Reduce(intersect, 
                     list=(Thre1[[1]],Thre2[[1]],Thre3[[1]],...,Thre10[[1]])
```

How can I write the code to prevent repeating typing `Threi[[j]]` by hand?

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all lists have the same length:

```
lapply(1:length(Thre1), function(i)
   Reduce(intersect, list(Thre1[[i]], ..., Thre10[[i]])))
```

Comment: @hora sorry my first answer was wrong, now I think it's correct.

Comment: And how about in the list(Thre1[[i]],...,Thre10[[i]]) ? should I repeat the list names or is it a way to produce them automatically? because I have so many lists also with other names like Rank1 ... Rank10 and so on.

Comment: The first thing to do is to change your 10 lists to list:

Thre = list(Thre1,Thre2,Thre3,Thre4,Thre5,Thre6,Thre7,Thre8,Thre9,Thre10)

This will make your life easier!

Comment: You can follow @Ali's advice by doing `myList <- lapply(paste0("Thre",1:10),get)` but you will be better off in the long run restructuring code to define these as list elements in the first place

Comment: The problem is that right now I have so many nested lists and I prefer not to make more variables but producing them automatically.

Comment: @Ali , I did your suggestion but again I need to write: output[[1]] = Reduce(intersect,list(Thre[[1]][[1]],Thre[[2]][[1]],Thre[[3]][[1]],...,Thre[[10]][[1]]) dont I? Now I am confused. Can you reproduce the intersect code depends on your suggestion? Thanks in advance